# Xamarin Forms - Wordpress REST API - See Username and Password

Tags: c#, json, wordpress, xamarin.forms, wordpress-rest-api

Is there a way I can return the username and password of a particular user using the Wordpress API?

Wordpress seems to have the password field as WRITE-ONLY in their API documentation.

I can pull the user's details in POSTMAN by doing a simple API call here:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers?consumer_key=xxxx&consumer_secret=xxxx&email=xxxx
```

And here's the result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 29288,
        "date_created": "2020-07-09T22:48:47",
        "date_created_gmt": "2020-07-09T12:48:47",
        "date_modified": "2020-08-12T23:19:16",
        "date_modified_gmt": "2020-08-12T13:19:16",
        "email": "xxxxu",
        "first_name": "xxxx",
        "last_name": "xxxx",
        "role": "customer",
        "username": "xxxx",
        "billing": {
            "first_name": "xxx",
            "last_name": "xxxx",
```

But I can't see the user's password.

The reason why I want to see the user's password so that my app can validate the username and password that was entered in the login screen against the returned json response before proceeding to the next page.

If this is due to security policies, any recommendations on how you could validate username / password against Wordpress API?

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: If you can get user's password just by calling an API, wouldn't that be a security flaw? I am sure no system would reveal passwords of their users. If you want to check if user's credentials are correct against WordPress then you need to check if WordPress offers such integration where you would delegate authentication to WordPress and word press tell you whether users is a legit WordPress user or not.

Comment: Thanks @ChetanRanpariya yes I believe it's due to security, was hoping to see if anyone had a solution to this.

Comment: that would be a HUGE security hole affecting millions of WP sites.  If you want to authenticate a user, you send their credentials to the API and the API tells you if they are valid or not.  See https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Comment: You can do the opposite.  A valid response would have a 200 OK.  So if you get any thing else it would be an error.  Normally http errors are 400/500.  Each type error has a different meaning. if the mountain won't come to Muhammad, Muhammad must go to the mountain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem. Need to use JWT Auth plugin and you can get authenticate the username and password.